# How to reset all iptables settings?

Tags: iptables

Are there any simpler commands to these? (e.g.: a oneliner? can one command reset iptables/netfilter settings to this?)

```
IPTABLES="$(which iptables)"

# RESET DEFAULT POLICIES
$IPTABLES -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t nat -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t nat -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t mangle -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t mangle -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# FLUSH ALL RULES, ERASE NON-DEFAULT CHAINS
$IPTABLES -F
$IPTABLES -X
$IPTABLES -t nat -F
$IPTABLES -t nat -X
$IPTABLES -t mangle -F
$IPTABLES -t mangle -X
```

Comment: Did you write this script or if not, would you have the source?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It only gets simpler if you *know* that you haven't changed some of these default chains. Other than that, no, this is as simple as it gets. *except for the fact that you can put `#!/bin/sh` at the top and put it in a file and wham, one liner*

Comment: Maybe if you have iptables as a module, you can unload it (and its cousins) and load it again?